# how to reuse lua vm created by lua_newstate?

Tags: multithreading, lua

Sometimes we need to use the whole lua vm as work unit, e.g. dispatch
the work unit among OS threads. However, it's a bit overhead at the
lua_newstate and lua_close. Is it feasible to reuse the vm after
cleanup (keep sandboxing)?

My simple idea is to create a work thread within the vm (create new _ENV for sandboxing), resume the thread to complete the work, and then remove the thread and put the vm into free pool for later reuse.

I wrote a simple program to verify it.

**test.c:**

```c
#include <lua.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  const int max = 100000;
  if (argc > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
      luaL_openlibs(L);
      luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua");
      lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
      assert(lua_tointeger(L, 1) == 49995000);
      lua_close(L);
    }
  }
  else {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "gtm");
    lua_pushglobaltable(L);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      lua_State* co = lua_newthread(L);
      luaL_loadfile(co, "test.lua");
      lua_newtable(co);
      luaL_setmetatable(co, "gtm");
      lua_setupvalue(co, 1, 1);
      lua_resume(co, NULL, 0);
      assert(lua_tointeger(co, 1) == 49995000);
      lua_settop(L, 0);
      lua_gc(L, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);
    }
    lua_close(L);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**test.lua:**

```lua
local total = 0
for i=0,10000-1 do
  total = total + i
end
return total
```

**output:**

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -llua -lm -ldl

$ time ./test state

real    0m21.470s
user    0m20.472s
sys 0m0.980s

$ time ./test

real    0m14.933s
user    0m14.036s
sys 0m0.872s
```

It seems that the simple reuse only saves 30% CPU, which is far from perfect.

Any better solution?

Comment: Why are you loading the script every time? Why not load it once and call whatever function you need to in a loop? Also, why the coroutine?

Comment: Because every work unit is individual and has different entry script, and they shouldn't share anything to each other. You could consider the vm/coroutine as the logic container, the logic could be reloaded, and the container should be reused. The coroutine is one of the idea to reuse the vm in cheap way.

Comment: Coroutine is the key of standboxing! In lua >= 5.2, nothing is shared between coroutines except registry and string intern tables (the _ENV refers to the global table by default, which is in turn an value within the registry indexed by LUA_RIDX_GLOBALS). And see my codes above, I replace the _ENV of the new corotuine with new table each time I reuse the vm, after resuming, the coroutine and the table are removed, and that's the cleanup what I means.